# Code in title; word 'LaTeX', 'TeX'

Tags: feature-request, formatting

Let's consider a brother site of our site, [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

```
\begin{feature-request}
```

---

```
\item [Monospaced code in the title]
```

Math.SE, of course, is specified for mathematics, so the reason why MathJax is loaded there is clear. We can type math equations in the question **as well as in the title**:

[image]

I don't ask for loading MathJax in TeX.SE because we don't really need it. However, TeX.SE is a site about TeX, LaTeX and ConTeXt, so what we really need is `code`.

Actually, we can now type code in questions very easily (all of you know it). However, we can't type code in the title of the questions, so the title now look not so good

[image]

Personally I **do** prefer

> Syntax similar to `\centering` for right and left?

to

> Syntax similar to \centering for right and left?

So why a feature for "coding" sites, like SO, TeX.SE, etc., for code in the title, hasn't been introduced yet?

---

```
\item [Type \TeX, \LaTeX{} correctly in TeX.SE]
```

Again, let's look at Math.SE. We can type the word L<sup>A</sup>T<sub>E</sub>X in the right format by using MathJax:

[image]

I'm wondering why a site not too related to T<sub>E</sub>X, L<sup>A</sup>T<sub>E</sub>X can show the word correctly when TeX.SE can not. It is a bit odd.

I think there is no need to load MathJax here, but we should have a tool to type `$\TeX$` and `$\LaTeX$` correctly!

---

```
\end{feature-request}
```

<sup>Note: I really think this question (or a part of it) is a duplicate, because the topic is quite popular. However, I can't find one question on Meta related to this. I'm sorry if this is a duplicate</sup>

Comment: I think it would be better to split this in two questions, one for each of your \items

Comment: For the code in title thingy, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76439, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68844 (related https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82013). I guess this would be a network-wide issue anyway.

Comment: Note that https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68869 is an answer by one of the co-founders of SE/SO, so at least at that time that was probably company policy. I'm not sure if anything has changed since then. But even if it did, it might still be a case of 'we did well so far without this feature' and 'if it ain't broke ...'.

Comment: Because  `MathJaX` can not handle any TeX output? ;-) We have this question basically every other week

Comment: @moewe The last re-design proofed that ` 'if it ain't broke ...'` is no valid reason for the Powers that Be not to change things